# Where did "Week" and "Month" go?

Tags: support, question-lists

Under the Ask Question button, Meta still has the original set of links:

[image: Active/Hot/Week/Month]

But on Stack Overflow itself, this seems to have happened:

[image: Newest/Interesting/Bountied/Hot]

Why?

Comment: Those buttons are still there for me... I've got Interesting, Bountied, Hot, Week, Month, in that order

Comment: It still looks good on my machine, even after a hard refresh.  Which suggests you were picked to take part in an A/B test.  One benefit I see is that "Newest" is certainly more helpful than "Active", too many edits.  Well, that's the half-full glass view.

Comment: Strange, the button seems to have migrated over from the "all questions" page. I wonder if it'll behave differently in the home view.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll be happy to trade.  

Comment: I hope this isn't an indicator that they're thinking about getting rid of the "interesting" tab. I'd be... quite irritated if all of a sudden the primary way I find interesting questions is gone and i have to put together some kind of tag-based query to get decent results.